# Running multiple rails tasks on heroku with the same worker that resque runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, resque, amazon-sqs

With the command below, I start a worker running the [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque)

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

**But I want to know:** Since I will be paying for a whole worker only to run resque, why can't run multiple running tasks?

For example: I need to poll a AWS SQS and it would be wasteful to have another worker for this poll.

I tried to put then: Resque, AWS_QUEUE to listen converted files. But Heroku crashes the worker.

```
=== worker: `bundle exec rake worker:all`
worker.1: crashed for 2m
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec rake worker:all
```

**worker.rake**

```
namespace :worker do
   task :all => [:environment, "sqs:listen_converted", "resque:work"] do
     puts "All workers started"
   end
end
```

**sqs.rake**

```
task "sqs:listen_converted" => :environment do

   puts "Start to listen converted..."

   Thread.new do
      queue = AWS::SQS::Queue.new(SQSADDR['incoming'])
      queue.poll do |msg|
      ...
   end
end
```

Can it be done? Thanks!!

Comment: `heroku logs` will show why it's crashing. `crashed` means the process exited unexpectedly twice in rapid succession; see [Managing Heroku Processes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps#process-restarts) for more.